# JS code to refresh a page at the minute 50 of every hour

Tags: javascript

I have the following code that will refresh the "updt" page at the minute "50" of every hour.
It only works if I refresh the page manually. How can I modify the code to sense that the minute 50 has come.

```
function show_hide_me () {
  var myDate = new Date();
  var mins = myDate.getMinutes();
    if (mins == 50){
       doSomething();
    } 
 }

 function doSomething() {
   alert("Page will refresh now");
    document.getElementById("updt").click();

}
```

Comment: So what is `document.getElementById("updt").click();` doing?

Comment: so why not call `window.reload(true)`

Comment: I don´t see any code that will force the code to be executed when you need it. You will need some kind of loop or event that will execute your code.

Comment: Either putting window.reload(true) or my code, it is not auto refreshing the page with both.

Comment: @el solo lobo, an example will be excellent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you are missing is that you need to check if its 50th minute, every minute.

```
setInterval(function(){
    show_hide_me();
}, 60*1000);
```

This will run your function every 60000 miliseconds i.e. one minute.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

Answer (score 0):

As other users said, what you need is a loop and a method like `window.reload(true)` or `window.location.href = location.href` to be executed when `mins == 50`.

For example, use `setInterval`:

```js
let intervalId = window.setInterval(function() {
    let myDate = new Date();
    let mins = myDate.getMinutes();
    if (mins == 50){
        window.location.href = location.href;
    } 
}, 60 * 1000); // every 60 seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is wrap your function in a

> setInterval
>   So that it can be executed maybe ever minute and would continuously check if it's 50minutes into an hour already.

A sample code would be:

```
setInterval(show_hide_me, 60000)
```

The reason for this is if the user happens to refresh the page, our checker would always execute our checker.

I think you should change your doSomething function to something like:

```
function doSomething() {
  window.location = window.location.href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this logic. This will refresh the page at the 50th minute for every hour.

```js
(function() {
  var time = 49 - (new Date()).getMinutes();
  time = time >= 0 ? time : (50 + (10 + time));
  console.log("Loaded : ", time);
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.reload();
  }, time*60000);
})()
```